# Caret position on second touch iOS 8

Tags: javascript, ios

i have an input field, in a browser where the content is not shown entirely,Like below image.

[image]

The webpage is for tablets and phones. If I want to make a correction before Submit, on the first touch the caret is positioned where the touch happens but if I want to correct my position on second touch the caret is positioned at the end of the text not where the touch happens, I have this strange behavior only on iOS 8. It's annoying on small tablets since the content usually is longer than the input field.
Is there a way to position the caret where the touch happens?